# Replace "this field is required" message in django admin

Tags: django, validation, django-admin, django-forms

is there a way to replace the default error message in django admin. I'm using custom widget so I have the form and I was wondering is there something like:
    `field_1 = forms.Charfield(widget=X, error_messge='y')`

I already tried to add claen_field_1 method but it looks that it is not called when the field is empty. Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466499

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes there is and actually this is forms functionality and not admin functionality ;), you can use this anywhere.

```
field_1 = forms.Charfield(widget=X, error_messages={'required': 'y'})
```

for more information see the [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages)